# Webpacker can't find application in manifest.json

Tags: ruby-on-rails, node.js, ruby, webpack, yarnpkg

My app works fine on my workstation but I don't know why it doesn't on my laptop. This is what I get when I go to **localhost:3000**

```
Webpacker::Manifest::MissingEntryError at /
    Webpacker can't find application in /home/max/app_project/public/packs/manifest.json. Possible causes:
    1. You want to set webpacker.yml value of compile to true for your environment
       unless you are using the `webpack -w` or the webpack-dev-server.
    2. webpack has not yet re-run to reflect updates.
    3. You have misconfigured Webpacker's config/webpacker.yml file.
    4. Your webpack configuration is not creating a manifest.
    Your manifest contains:
    {
    }
```

I ran **$yarn** command and I got the following;

```
yarn install v1.21.1
[1/4] Resolving packages...
[2/4] Fetching packages...
error @rails/webpacker@4.2.2: The engine "node" is incompatible with this module. Expected version ">=8.16.0". Got "8.10.0"
error Found incompatible module.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/install for documentation about this command.
```

Comment: You can try updating Node itself. Also I feel this doesn't belong to SO but to Server Fault (I'll vote for moving the question).

Comment: Vote on [this proposal](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/354583/disentangle-the-yarn) to ease the tag confusion around [yarn] and [yarnpkg].

Answer (score 0):

Ok so i fixed this error. 
I updated my **node** and run **$yarn** command.
The error is gone!

Thanks everyone!